# Can an iPhone/iPod Touch application open a port for remote communication without jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, controls, ipod, ports

I'm researching remote control testing for an app that'll be installed on the new iPod Touch and can't tell for certain from everything that I've read whether or not an installed app can or can't open *any* ports for remote test instructions (that's a mouthful : )  We created something like this for the Android using adb port forwarding and telnet, and it worked really well.  Is there any chance something similar could be done on an iPhone or iPod without jailbreaking??

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have access to the traditional Unix networking layer and a Cocoa layer built on top of that as well.

Comment: @Ukko: Thank you, can you recommend any good reference docs for opening tcp ports?

Comment: Also, I didn't make clear in my question description that I need to open this port on the iPod, not a remote server.  Tests running on my local machine would then telnet to the connected/tethered iPod where my app would be waiting for instructions to drive the app for story tests verification.  Hope this all makes sense.  Thanks!